# AngularJS - HTTP Error handling - Generic and specific handling

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, interceptor

I need to implement error handling in my system and for that I am using the $httpProvider.interceptors.

My problem is that in some use cases I have a generic handling and some not.

I am using this practice : http://michalostruszka.pl/blog/2013/09/06/selective_http_errors_handling_in_angularjs/

But the problem is that because I am using $resource object, I don't know how dynamically I can add parameter ('bypassErrorInterceptor') to the config object.

Thanks everyone!